# SQL Server logins are locked out but not really locked out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I create Logins for a lot of people. They work mostly but a few now and then behave like this:
Logins are authenticated through SQL Server Authentication. The person gets this message:
[image]

When I look at the Login I see this:
[image]

So it tells me they are not locked out. I have to edit their pw and the login starts working again. I don't even have to change the PW, I just re-enter the current one. Am I missing something?

Here is the script that creates the Login:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateLogins]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @newdb sysname
    DECLARE @studentID AS varchar(20)
    begin try
        close student_cursor
        DEALLOCATE student_cursor
    end try
    begin catch
    end catch
    DECLARE student_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT UserName FROM tStudent where studentid>35
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)

OPEN student_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM student_cursor
INTO @studentID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Create the user name
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + ltrim(rtrim(@StudentID)) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''P@ssword1'', DEFAULT_DATABASE=' + ltrim(rtrim(@StudentID)) + ', CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON';
    print @SQL
    EXECUTE(@SQL);

FETCH NEXT FROM student_cursor
INTO @studentID
END


END
```

Comment: Anything in the SQL Server event log for these accounts such as previous failed logins?
Also, what do you see under Security Settings-->Account Policies-->AccountLockout policy in secpol.msc?

Comment: Might be a better fit over on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I looked in Security Settings-->Account Policies-->AccountLockout policy in secpol.msc as suggested by @SEarle1986. I had no idea a lockout could be temporary. :)

[image]